# vacuously true for empty set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

[image]

I don't understand why if $D$ is an empty set, then $P(x)\rightarrow Q(x) $ is true. My understanding is, if $D$ is an empty set, then there is no $x$ to choose, so we can't tell truth values of $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$, because $x$ is empty

Comment: They are not referring to the statement $(P (x) \rightarrow Q (x) )$, but the statement $(\forall x \in D, P (x) \rightarrow Q(x) ) $. This is vacuous true because,  since $D $ is empty, it is not saying anything.

Comment: Using proof by contradiction will make it easier to understand.

Comment: It has to holds for all $x\in D$. Since there are none, this statement is true.

Comment: @Shagnik  I understand $D$ is empty, it is not saying anything, so shouldn't the statement be uncertain? Because we can't tell $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$?

Comment: Can you produce a counter-example?

Comment: There is no truth value called "uncertain".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement $\forall x\in\varnothing, P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$ isn't false. Indeed, if it were false, then its contrary
$$\exists x\in\varnothing, P(x)\wedge \neg Q(x)$$
would be true. Since $\varnothing$ is empty, such an $x$ can't exist, hence the contrary is false and the first statement is (vacuously) true.